# Removing the "Popular Terms" area from the Taxonomy Edit Screen in the Admin Area

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, customization, taxonomy

Personally I really dislike how wordpress shows all the "popular terms" in different sizes on the taxonomy add/edit screen in the admin area.

Does anyone know of a way to either remove this entire area completely by adding code to your functions.php file

and/or

how to just change this specific area so that none of the popular terms show up with different font sizes/styles?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I love it when you give me an easy one. Starts to make up for all those harder ones... *(well, partly. ;-)*

So what you want is to replace this:

[image: WordPress Tag Cloud with mixed-sized fonts]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20110122-011017.png))</sub>

With this:

[image: WordPress Tag Cloud with consistently-sized fonts]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/Post_Tags_%E2%80%B9_WordPress_3.0_Test_Site_%E2%80%94_WordPress-20110122-011719.png))</sub>

How? Use the `'wp_tag_cloud'` hook which you can put into your theme's `functions.php` file or in a `.php` file of a plugin you might be writing.  For this one I tested the global variable `$pagenow` to make sure it was on the term edit page. In the hook just strip out the `style` attribute from each of the `<a>` elements:

```
add_action('wp_tag_cloud','modify_taxonomy_tag_cloud',10,2);
function modify_taxonomy_tag_cloud($html,$args) {
  global $pagenow;
  if ('edit-tags.php'==$pagenow) // Only for the tag edit page
    $html = preg_replace("#style='[^']+'#Us",'',$html);
  return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to offer up an alternative using a CSS override which will actually have the same effect as Mike's solution.

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-edit-tags.php', 'normalize_tag_cloud' );
function normalize_tag_cloud() {
    ?>  
    <style type="text/css">.tagcloud a { font-size:inherit!important }</style>
    <?php
}
```

I don't think either way is better, simply wanted to share a way to approach the problem differently.. ;)

Comment: Good one! I tried CSS first but couldn't get it to work, doh! Guess that proves how bad I suck at CSS!  I also just learned about the `'admin_print_styles-*'` hook from your answer too. +1

Comment: I taught you something, lol... didn't see that coming.. (i'm jesting incase it's not obvious).. I'd have thought you'd know your CSS pretty well, it's relatively easy when compared with PHP(imho). Happy to have expanded your pool of WP knowledge..! :)